# Process the del key from keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, keyboard

I would like to also receive the `del` key from the keyboard, which appears via the `UiView`.

The default action is that it does not appear in the text field, but removes the existing previous character.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what do you want?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the UITextFieldDelegate protocol method [`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991-CH3-SW9) to intercept the deletion of a character.

> **textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:**
>
> Asks the delegate if the specified
>   text should be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which solved the initial problem. However the delete/backspace key is still not passed through without any processing at all. I have also discovered other keys that I will also need, so I will probably end up creating a special keyboard. John